# Error when detaching volume using hdiutil on OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, volume, detach

Ive got a program that runs on Mac OS 10.5.8. The program runs a continuous cycle where it mounts an image, installs a browser plugin and unmounts the image again. If I leave this program running I eventually end up in a situation where I get the following error "fork: resource temporarily unavailable". In the activity monitor I can see that several hundreds of processes called diskimages-helper are running. Does anyone know why this happens and how I can avoid it? Below are the commands I use during one cycle of the program.

```
# First I remove the plugin
rm -rf "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/my.plugin"

# If the mount exists I unmount it
hdiutil unmount [mount] -force

# If that doesnt work I detach the device
hdiutil detach [device] -force

# Then I mount the image
hdiutil mount [image]

# I install the plugin
installer -package [package] -target /

# Unmount
hdiutil unmount [mount] -force

# And if necessary detach
hdiutil detach [device] -force
```

Comment: You're repeatedly installing the same browser plugin?

Comment: The program does some other stuff making it useful :) It downloads a different revision of the plugin and runs some tests

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to *always* detach the disk image -- unmounting it unmounts the filesystem, but leaves disk image attached to a /dev/disk* entry, with a diskimages-helper process running to handle it.  Note that `hdiutil detach` will take care of unmounting the volume for you (provided Disk Arbitration is running), so you can just skip the unmount step.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Ill give it a shot. (Its hard to say if it works as the problem sometimes takes days to manifest, its not like each cycle adds a diskimages process)

Comment: Hey Gordon, I finally got around to trying your suggestion, and it seems to work :) thanks

Comment: It's quite unfortunate that `mount` is a synonym for `attach` but `unmount` is not a synonym for `detach`.  This tripped me up, slowly filled `/dev` with `disk*` entries, eventually leading to a `no mountable file systems` error.  Rebooting to clear the `/dev/disk*` entries and using `attach`/`detach` in place of `mount`/`unmount` looks to have solved the problem.